# how to parametrize button style in WPF xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a template button with a specific effect that can receive 2 background images as parameters (for button pushed and released). this template is implemented in a user control library :

```
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SwitchesLibrary">
<Style x:Key="PushButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="MyBorder" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonPressedOnClick" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="5" Background="{DynamicResource ButtonPressed}" BorderThickness="1">
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonPressedOnClick" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05" Value="1.0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05" Value="0.0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonReleased}"/>
</Style>
```

I use it in another user control library, but i don't know how to send the parameters `{DynamicResource ButtonReleased}` and `{DynamicResource ButtonPushed}`
:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/SwitchesLibrary;component/PushButton.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Button Name="ButtonA" Style="{StaticResource PushButton, ButtonPressed="Images/PushButtons/A_Pushed.png", ButtonReleased="Images/PushButtons/A_Released.png"}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Click="ButtonA_Click" Margin="69,112,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest solution to 'parameterizing' a `Style` would be to override the image resources in the `Button` itself, but this would be rather verbose and cumbersome to do more than a few times:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource PushButton}">
  <Button.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="ButtonPressed"
                ImageSource="Images/PushButtons/A_Pushed.png" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="ButtonReleased"
                ImageSource="Images/PushButtons/A_Released.png" />
  </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

If this is something you're going to use more than a couple times, it's worth investing a little more time upfront to make your image button easier to use.  Wouldn't it be more convenient to type this instead?

```xml
<l:ImageButton NormalImage="Images/PushButtons/A_Released.png"
               PressedImage="Images/PushButtons/A_Pushed.png" />
```

If you like the look of that, then the first step would be to write a simple `ImageButton` class and define dependency properties for the images representing the various button states:

```cs
public class ImageButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "NormalImage",
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource NormalImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(NormalImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NormalImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PressedImage",
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource PressedImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(PressedImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressedImageProperty, value); }
    }

    static ImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
    }
}
```

The second step is to define a **default style** for your `ImageButton`.  To do this, create a `Themes\Generic.xaml` resource dictionary in the project where `ImageButton` is declared.  Make sure the Build Action is set to 'Page' in the Properties pane.  Implement your default style here, for example:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestApp">

  <Style TargetType="l:ImageButton"
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="l:ImageButton">
          <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
              <Image x:Name="image"
                     Source="{TemplateBinding NormalImage}"
                     Stretch="None"
                     HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="image"
                      Property="Source"
                      Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PressedImage}" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Check your project's `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and make sure you have an attribute like this (and add it if you don't):

```cs
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    // Where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    // (used if a resource is not found in the page, or application
    // resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,

    // Where the generic resource dictionary is located
    // (used if a resource is not found in the page, app, or 
    // any theme specific resource dictionaries)                                 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly 
)]
```

And now you're ready to go!

```xml
<l:ImageButton NormalImage="Images/PushButtons/A_Released.png"
               PressedImage="Images/PushButtons/A_Pushed.png" />
```